# C++: Import/Include system

Tags: c++, import, package

I'm writing a programming language, that convert the source files to C++ and compile they.

I want to add an way to work with a large number of files, compiling they to `.o` files, making it possible to use makefiles. A Better explanation (thank @Beta):

> You have a tool that reads a source file (`foo.FN`) and writes C++ source and header files (`foo.cpp` and `foo.h`). Then a compiler (`gcc`) reads those source and header files (`foo.cpp` and `foo.h`) and writes an object file (`foo.o`). And maybe there are interdependencies (`bar.cpp` needs `foo.h`).

The problem is: my interpreter delete the `.cpp` and `.h` after the GCC compile they. Because this, it can't use `#include`, cause when it will compile, the referenced files don't exist anymore. How I can solve this?

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand what you are asking for. Usually compilation is automated through `Makefile`, `Rakefile` or any other **build automation** project. I don't think you want to **delete** your source code after compilation, I think you may want to `clean` the state of your project from time to time (that means: removing intermediate objects `.o`, or removing final linked executable). Using a build automation software allows you to compile only that intermediate files that depend upon changed sources, thus reducing compilation time.

Comment: @MatteoRagni My program will create C++ files end compile it, so I don't want the user to see the files because he will work with my language, not C++. For this I need to delete the files before compilation. For user to be able to use `makefiles` or something like it, the program need to compile to `.o`, but I don't want the save the C++ files.

Comment: Sorry, but IMHO you have to carefully rewrite your question. I really have difficulties in understanding what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MatteoRagni I'm having serious problems with English. I edited the post, I hope I have improved it.

Comment: You have a tool that reads a source file (`foo.FN`) and writes C++ source and header files (`foo.cpp` and `foo.h`). Then a compiler (`gcc`) reads those source and header files (`foo.cpp` and `foo.h`) and writes an object file (`foo.o`). And maybe there are interdependencies (`bar.cpp` needs `foo.h`). Is that correct?

Comment: @Beta Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer.

First, don't write explicit header files. You know what they should contain, just perform the `#include` operation yourself.

Secondly, don't write out the `.cpp` file either. Use `gcc -x c++ -` to read the code from standard input, and have your tool emit C++ to standard out, so you can run `tool foo.FN | gcc -c -o foo.o -x c++ -` to produce `foo.o`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you know somewhere to read how the Python or GoLang `import` work?

Comment: @FelipeNascimento: Any basic tutorial. But when you're still struggling with that, writing your own language is not going to be realistic.

Comment: I'm asking about how the their compiler do the import. For example, I know the `#include` of C++ copy the content of header.